# PHP Skip something a certain amout of times in loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, html-table

I have a ton of `for` loops for generating a table, with results from my MySQL DB. Some of the more important information are the start and end date. I calculate how many days this absence has besides the start date(For example 02.03.2015 - 04.03.2015, 2 days). I save this result in `$difference`, however I get this result during a for loop, so I cant simply go to the for loop and say `$xyz - difference`.

So I thought about skiping the `<td>'`s in the loop, as many times as the difference.

Here in the picture you see that the `<td>`'s are off the amount of days the absence lasts.

[image]

How can I skip them as many times as the difference, so the tables looks right again?

My code is still a mess so no comments about that:

```
echo '<table class="table table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">';
echo '<thead>';
for ($l = 0; $l < $days; $l++) {
    if ($l == 0) {
        echo '<th>', '<b>Day</b>', '</th>';
    } else {
        $date = "$current-$month-$l";
        $date = date('D', strtotime($date));
        $date = substr($date, 0, -1);
        echo '<th class="center">', $date,'</th>';
    }
    echo "\n";
}

echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';

for ($l = 0; $l < $days; $l++) {
    if ($l == 0) {
        echo '<td>', '<b>Onshore</b>', '</td>';
    } else {
        echo '<th class="center">', $l, '</th>';
    }
    echo "\n";
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $count_user; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';        
    $result = mysql_query("select start, end, type_FK, employee_FK FROM absences where employee_FK = {$array_user[$i]['employee_ID']} and MONTH(start) = $month and YEAR(start) = $current");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array_absences[] = $row;
    }

    $count = 0;
    if (!empty($array_absences)) {
        $count = count($array_absences);
    }

    for ($j = 0; $j < $days; $j++) {
        $true = 0;
        if ($j == 0 && $i == $count_on) {
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<b>Offshore</b>';
            echo '</td>';
            for($k = 0; $k < $days -1; $k++){
                echo '<td>';
                echo '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }

        if ($j == 0) {
            echo '<td>';
            echo $array_user[$i]['name'], ' ', $array_user[$i]['surname'];
            echo '</td>';
        }

        for ($k = 0; $k < $count; $k++) {       
            $array_absences[$k]['start'] = substr($array_absences[$k]['start'], -2);
            $array_absences[$k]['end']   = substr($array_absences[$k]['end'], -2);
            $array_absences[$k]['start'] = ereg_replace("^0", "", $array_absences[$k]['start']);
            $array_absences[$k]['end']   = ereg_replace("^0", "", $array_absences[$k]['end']);      
            $difference = $array_absences[$k]['end'] - $array_absences[$k]['start'];    

            if ($j == $array_absences[$k]['start'] && $array_absences[$k]['employee_FK'] == $array_user[$i]['employee_ID']) {
                $true = 1;
                $result = mysql_query("select approved from absences where DAY(start) = $j and MONTH(start) = $month");
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $approved[] = $row;
                    $n++;
                }

                $now = date('Y-m-d');
                $absence = strtotime("$current/$month/$j");
                $absence = date('Y-m-d',$absence);

                for ($q = 0; $q < $difference+1; $q++) {
                    if ($approved[$n]['approved'] == 1) {
                        echo '<td class="center green">';
                    } elseif ($approved[$n]['approved'] == 0 && $now <= $absence) {
                        echo '<td class="center orange">';
                    } elseif ($approved[$n]['approved'] == 0 && $now > $absence) {
                        echo '<td class="center red">';
                    }

                    for ($l = 0; $l < $count_types; $l++) {

                        if ($array_absences[$k]['type_FK'] == $types[$l]['type_ID']) {
                            echo $types[$l]['short'];
                        }
                    }

                    echo '</td>';
                }
            }

        }       

        //Days that are not absences                    

        //Skip this the amounts of $difference
        echo '<td ';

        //If weekend special coloring
        $date = "$current-$month-$j+1";
        $date = new DateTime($date);
        $day =  $date->format("w");             

        if ($day == 6 || $day == 0) {
            echo 'class = "weekend"';   
        }

        echo '>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo "\n";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: I will not comment on the mess. But please do not use mysql_* functions, they are depreciated and with good reason.

Comment: If you want a table with more than one row, then you can’t simply “skip” table cells – you either have to output empty cells, or use `colspan` to match the overall cell count in each row.

Comment: @Luceos I'm aware of this, however security does not matter at all in this application.

Comment: do your calculations first, then do the output loop

Comment: @charlietfl I think this is the best solution...

Comment: @Luceos mysql_ functions are *deprecated*. I'm not sure what impact this may have had on their value. ;-)

Comment: @Gintoki Sorry, but this is a mess. It's ridiculous to execute queries *inside* a loop.

Comment: @Strawberry, I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I did not really get the sense of your explanations, however, to skip something in a loop, you can use the **continue** keyword for this.

For example :

```
for($i = 0; $i++; i<1000){
    if($i < 200 && $i > 100)
        continue;
    // Computations are here....
}
```

Comment: But how can I skip it x times? In my example I need to skip 2 times.

Comment: @Gintoki, where exactly do you need to skip? and what is the constraint ?(why would you skip in that iteration)

Comment: It's really hard to explain, but I think the base of my logic is wrong. Would it help you if I post the whole code with the DB?

Comment: I found the solution, however it's not very clean.